# using saxon extensions with ProfessionalTransformerFactory FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING

Tags: saxon

I know this question has been answered in a way before, but I am trying to get some definitive answers.

I am trying to adapt the barcode4j extension that was written long ago for xalan 8, which we use in FOP transformations from xml data to pdf through xslt.

I requested and received an evaluation license for Saxon PE, and in fits and starts I was able to modify the barcode4j extension to work with Saxon PE version 10.6!  I was overjoyed until I realized that Saxon Extensions of all types are disallowed when FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING is set true.  So my questions are these:

Is there still no exception in any version of Saxon for extensions that are specifically registered in the config?

Do I need to build on my progress and create a Saxon function instead, a la the Sql functions?

Having done that, would I be able to do something as simple as this (for example):

```
        File f = new File ("/tmp/config.txt");
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource(f);
        //Setup XSLT
        Configuration config = Configuration.readConfiguration(source);
        ProfessionalTransformerFactory factory = (ProfessionalTransformerFactory) TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setConfiguration(config);
        Processor processor = (Processor) config.getProcessor();

        // Here extension happens, test comes from class Test -> Test.java
        ExtensionFunction  barcode = new BarcodeFunction() ;
        processor.registerExtensionFunction(barcode);
        factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
      Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        //Setup input for XSLT transformation
        Source src = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml));

        
        //Resulting SAX events (the generated FO) must be piped through to FOP
        Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

        //Start XSLT transformation and FOP processing
        transformer.transform(src, res);
```

And assuming a function, approximately how would this adapt to our xslt:

```
                                                               <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="18pt">
                                                                  <fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                                                    <bc:barcode message="{//packing_list_d/@packing_list_no}" orientation="90">
                                                                    <code39>
                                                                            <height>18.635mm</height>
                                                                            <module-width>0.25mm</module-width>
                                                                            <human-readable>none</human-readable>
                                                                            <quiet-zone enabled="true"/>
                                                                    </code39>
                                                                    </bc:barcode>                                                            
                                                                 </fo:instream-foreign-object>
                                                             </fo:block>
```

I think at one time we had played around with a custom java function and ended up with this:

```
                                                                     <xsl:variable name="barcode-cfg">
                                                                       <barcode orientation="90">
                                                                        <code39>
                                                                            <height>18.635mm</height>
                                                                            <module-width>0.25mm</module-width>
                                                                            <human-readable>none</human-readable>
                                                                            <quiet-zone enabled="true"/>
                                                                        </code39>
                                                                      </barcode>
                                                                     </xsl:variable>
                                                                   <xsl:copy-of select="barcode:generate($barcode-cfg, //packing_list_d/@packing_list_no)"/>
```

Is that about what we would need to do with a Saxon function?

I have read about how FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING is **not** necessarily "secure," but our customers and our consultants are able to upload xslt for fop transformations, so we do need both the secure feature and the ability to register and run our custom function for barcodes!!

Answer (score 0):

FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING is a pretty blunt instrument. I suspect that all the things it prevents you doing can be individually constrained using finer-grained mechanisms. If you want to disable some of the things it disallows and not others, then select those you want to disable and treat them one by one. For example you can disable external document access with a URIResolver, and you can disable untrusted reflexive extension functions by registering a DynamicLoader with the Configuration that checks what classes are being dynamically loaded and only allows those you want to allow.

Are you using FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING because you really don't trust the XSLT stylesheet author, or are you using it because it sounds good?

Comment: Frankly, we use xslt strictly to transform data in our application to PDF, and have no need to allow external document access or any miscellaneous functions.  We do use a URIResolver to prevent the stylesheet from trying to access a whole directory rather than an image, but that is solving a different problem.

And again, frankly, we are trying to satisfy security concerns from the perspective of our customers and the tools they and we have for identifying those concerns (veracode scan in our case).  Implementing fine-grained mechanisms won't satisfy that concern.

Comment: The effort here is to allow our customers to use XSLT 2.0 and still be able to use the barcode4j  fop extension.  additionally we are trying to comply with a security initiative.  Blunt or not, we need (and can live with) FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING as long as we can get barcode4j to work with it.

I was asking, if writing an implementation of ExtensionFunction would satisfy our needs.  I think the answer is "yes," but was hoping for something definitive.

Comment: You could implement similar functionality with an extension function, but you wouldn't be able to invoke it using the extension element syntax.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up implementing the fop barcode4j functionality with your integrated extension function (extends ExtensionFunctionDefinition), and it works fine.